# How do I ensure consistent image quality on RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I am running a UI automation program on the remote machine itself. This UI automation clicks buttons based on image recognition. I realize the image quality that exe recognizes is based on the image being displayed onto remote desktop. I tested this by having the same UI automation program take a screenshot when logged via RDP using 8-bit color. The screenshot taken shows 8-bit color depth even when viewed on another PC with 32-bit color depth.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Start -> Run. type mstsc. The RDC connection windows opens,
by clicking edit / options ,  head over to display tab and under Colours, select Highest quality (32-bit). and save your setting